# Statistics on the number of open questions

Tags: support, questions, unanswered-questions

Are there any stats available on this site which list the total number of questions, the number of open questions, the number of open questions with at least one answer scored greater than 1, and so on?

I ask because I have noticed that some questions with excellent answers have not been accepted.

Comment: This site (Meta) or the main site? Or both, even?

Comment: @AndrewLeach The main site ... but I suspect that it will be useful everywhere.

Comment: Have a look at the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/queries).

Comment: Go to http://english.stackexchange.com/questions, the number is in the top right. select a tab to get subsets (and their counts). sort by your choce, go to the last page to see extreme values.

Comment: @RegDwightАΑA Nifty! Cheers :) How do I tackle _this_ question now? Do you want to move your comment into an answer?

Comment: @Mitch: Thanks :) The Data Explorer was what I was looking for!

Comment: Yes, that's much more versatile. I just thought you were looking for some quck one time things that can be read off from the regular interface.

Comment: Oh, I wouldn't have expected that half-assed one-liner to be enough for you... Anyone is free to flesh it out a bit, to turn it into something more useful to less tech-savvy future visitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#answers you will see some statistics about Stack Exchange sites. It doesn't include all the statistics you are asking for, but it gives some important statistics.

[image: screenshot]

It also allows you to order the site by specific criteria.

[image: screenshot]

If you sort by traffic, for example, you get the following.

[image: screenshot]

I created a [Data Explorer query](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/76893/statistics-about-the-site-questions) that reports some of the statistics you asked for. The following is the graph created with that query.

[image: screenshot]

Keep in mind that the Data Explorer uses not updated data.

Comment: I was unaware of this. Thanks :) Please also include RegDwight's link (from the comments) in your answer as it is also pertinent.